# Should I download Python 2.7.6 Windows X86-64 Installer?

Tags: python, windows, download, installation

I have an HP laptop with a 64 bit operating system, and Windows 8. I have looked all over google and on the Python website itself, and I can't seem to find anything saying exactly what version of Python I should download. Is Python 2.7.6 Windows X86-64 Installer the correct version to install? The only other version that seems right is Python 2.7.6 Windows Installer, but I'm not sure what the difference is.

Comment: this is probably not the right place to put this particular kind of question - the programmers forum on stackexchange might be better. that said, if you are just getting into it, looking into a distribution like anaconda or enthought instead, and go 64 bit.

Comment: Did you look over this wiki guide? https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Download

Answer (score 2):

The Python 2.7.6 Windows Installer (32-bit Python) might have slightly more precompiled extension module compatability. The Python 2.7.6 Windows X86-64 Installer will give you something with a bit more memory capacity, which you probably don't need but might.

Comment: +1 this answer and I'd only add that **both** the 32bit and 64bit versions will work fine on your laptop. By your question, I'd assume you're fairly new to programming (at least with common cross-platform compiled/interpreted languages) and wouldn't even notice the difference. Just make sure if you use the 32bit version, you only install 32bit extension. Same goes for 64bit version and 64bit extensions.